# open a file in sublime and show that it needs saving

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am making a sublime plugin that makes changes to files which may not be open

```
f = open(file_name, 'r+')
text = f.read()
lines = text.splitlines()
for i in reversed(range(len(lines))): #iterate backwards
    #modifications to final_text made here
    if not text == final_text:
        #open before change so user can see which files changed and possibly undo
        sublime.active_window().run_command('open_file', {'file': file_name}) 

        #make change
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(final_text)
        f.truncate()
```

This indeed opens the file and edits the content as desired. But the file doesn't appear to require saving. I can hit undo and the edit is undone as expected. But why doesn't it require saving?

EDIT:
 if anyone reads this, skuroda's answer below was correct and lead to the following code

```
newView = sublime.active_window().open_file(file_name);
'''
note: you cant just do this:
newView.run_command('select_all')
newView.run_command('cut')
newView.run_command('insert_text', {'string': final_text})
because the file takes time to open, use a timeout instead...
'''
sublime.set_timeout(lambda: write_to_file(newView, final_text), 10)
```

and the timeout function like this

```
def write_to_file(newView, final_text):
    if not newView.is_loading():
        newView.run_command('select_all')
        newView.run_command('cut')
        newView.run_command('insert_text', {'string': final_text})
    else:
        sublime.set_timeout(lambda: write_to_file(newView, final_text), 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing to the file directly not within the context of ST. Note that in the above posted code, the only ST dependent code you have is opening the file. You are not using `view#erase`, `view#insert`, `view#replace` etc. As further demonstration of this, remove the open file from your plugin. The content of the file will still be updated, even though it's not "open" in the editor.

Comment: I don't actually have the view context so is there a way to get ST to trigger the is_dirty ?

Comment: Again, you are operating outside of ST with the above code. You are writing directly to the file. It is "saved" when you write to the file. That being said, you can get access to the view by using the `window#open_file` method rather than using `run_command`.

Comment: will ask a separate question if necessary.. but dont view#replace etc require a correct edit argument.. if I've opened an arbitrary file, my edit arg is incorrect and using view#replace does nothing

Comment: Correct, you will basically right a separate `sublime.TextCommand` to do the actual modification of the view. If you do ask another question about your plugin, it would be helpful to post a little more of the code, so we can recommend a good solution. Based on what you have here though, you can pass `final_text` and an argument to the view command, and should be able to get the correct result.